# TiKz tree not showing up correctly

Tags: tikz-trees

I am moving my project from Overleaf to Texlive with Texmaker in a computer running Manjaro. I need to use TiKz to create some trees in my document and they showed up correctly while using Overleaf, but now in my local machine they appear just as some character all one over each other. This is the code I used:

```
    \documentclass{article}    
    \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphs.standard}
    \usetikzlibrary{trees}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}


   \begin{document}
   \tikzset{
            treenode/.style = {shape=circle,
                 draw, align=center,
                 top color=white},
            root/.style     = {treenode, font=\ttfamily\normalsize},
            env/.style      = {treenode, font=\ttfamily\normalsize},
            leaf/.style    = {treenode,font=\ttfamily\normalsize,bottom color=red}
   }
  \begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=3cm, sibling distance=4.5cm]
  \tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=4cm, sibling distance=2.5cm]
  \tikzstyle{level 3}=[level distance=4cm, sibling distance=1cm]
  \begin{tikzpicture}
       [
        grow                    = right,
        sibling distance        = 3em,
        level distance          = 6em,
        edge from parent/.style = {draw, -latex},
        every node/.style       = {font=\footnotesize},
        sloped
        ]
        \node [root] {$\epsilon$}
        child { node [env] {1}
        child{ node [leaf] {11}
               edge from parent node [below] {1/P(1$|$1)}}
               child{ node [leaf] {01}
                      edge from parent node [above] {0/P(0$|$1)}}
                      edge from parent node [below] {1/P(1)} }
        child { node [env] {0}
                child{ node [leaf] {10}
                       edge from parent node [below] {1/P(1$|$0)}}
                child{ node [leaf] {00}
                       edge from parent node [above] {0/P(0$|$0)}}
                       edge from parent node [above] {0/P(0)} };
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{figure}

   \end{document}
```

Comment: `\tikzstyle` is deprecated. Which engine are you using? LuaTeX?

Comment: Just remove `\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}`

Comment: @salimbou You should answer. You were faster. @ OP Note that specifying `[h]` for `figure` is pointless. LaTeX will assume you cannot possibly mean it and ignore you. (It'll change it to `ht`, I think, to make it minimally sane.)

Comment: With `\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}` you need to compile with `LaTeX`, not `pdfLaTeX`. If you remove option [dvips] at `graphicx`, you can compile with `LaTeX` aw well with `pdfLaTeX`. Also all TikZ libraries, which you load, are surplus.

Comment: @salimbou That did the trick! You should answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by comments and no commenter wants to answer.